# how to merge two dictionaries based on key but include missing key values in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can we achieve below merge result if i have two dictionaries with different lengths with both similar and dissimilar keys .

```
left =  {key1: x1, key2: y1 , key3: z1 , key5 : n1}  
right = {key1: x2, key2: y2 , key4 : m1 ,key5 : n1}
```

result :

```
d =        { key1: {x1,x2},  
             key2: {y1,y2},
             key3: {z1,missing},
             key4 :{missing,m1}
             key5 :{n1,n1}
          }
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how was it deficient?

Comment: "both with similar and dissimilar keys": What does this mean?

Comment: Your posted code isn't legal Python.

Comment: this was working in my code.

sortedLeft  = dict(sorted(left.items()))
sortedRight = dict(sorted(right.items()))

merged = {k : (sortedLeft[k],sortedRight[k]) for k in sortedLeft.keys() & sortedRight.keys()}
sortedMerged = dict(sorted(merged.items()))

Comment: Above comment is to say that that dictionary is legal. my question was I'm not able to achieve this combination : key3: {z1,missing},
             key4 :{missing,m1}

Answer (score 4):

I use square brackets (lists) instead of curly (set) because it seems that for you order is important, and sets do not preserve the order of the elements.

```
 keys = set(left.keys()) | set(right.keys())
 d = {}
 for k in keys:
     d[k] = [left.get(k, 'missing'), right.get(k, 'missing')]
```

or slightly shorter with a comprehension notation

```
 keys = set(left.keys()) | set(right.keys())
 d = {k: [left.get(k, 'missing'), right.get(k, 'missing')] for k in keys}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
left =  {'key1': 'x1', 'key2': 'y1' , 'key3': 'z1' , 'key5' : 'n1'}  
right = {'key1': 'x2', 'key2': 'y2' , 'key4' : 'm1' ,'key5' : 'n1'}  
d=dict()

for key,val in left.items():
    d[key]=[val]
for key,val in right.items():
    if key in d.keys():
      d[key].append(val)
    else:
      d[key]=[val]

print(d)
>>>> {'key1': ['x1','x2'], 'key2': ['y1','y2'] , 'key3': ['z1'], 'key4':['m1'] , 'key5' : ['n1','n1']}
```

Comment: Hi @emilaz Thank you.  can we do this way :  key3: {z1,missing}, key4 :{missing,m1} because i want to track if the value is missing in left dictionary or right dictionary. for example, for key3 :  right dictionary has missing value.

Comment: In that case, I would go with Serge's answer :)

Comment: If all of the variables used in defining `left` and `right` are defined, the output would report their *values,* not the variable names.

Comment: you are correct, but it was the easiest way to give the OP the answer he was looking for. I will update my post to make it technically correct. Thanks for the heads up.